# Teradata SQL flag for last X distinct column permutations by rank

Tags: sql, teradata

My Teradata SQL query finds all unique fiscal year/fiscal week combinations in a table and orders them chronologically:

```
select
fiscalyear,fiscalweek,
fiscalyear||fiscalweek as yrwkperm
from table
qualify count(*) over (partition by yrwkperm rows unbounded preceding) = 1
order by fiscalyear,fiscalweek
```

I then take the resulting dataset and add another column that designates the chronological order of the weeks, but is simply the row number since I've ordered by fiscalyear,fiscalweek:

[Excel example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1d8E.png)

I then add another logical column that says (pseudocode)
If (chrono >= (max(chrono)-52+1)) then "Last52Weeks" else "NotLast52Weeks"

The expression in the parentheses will be TRUE if the fiscalyear/fiscalweek permutation is in the last 52 weeks of the dataset.  (I have no discontinuities in the list of distinct fiscalyear/fiscalweek permutations so I have no concerns about the row numbers not being the same as the chronological order of the weeks).

So my question is, can I create a column with the "last 52 weeks yes/no" binary flag, all inside a single TD SQL query?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm sure you can.  You should edit the question and include the logic that you using for the flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want (I changed the QUALIFY to a simple GROUP BY, should be more efficient):

```
select
   fiscalyear,fiscalweek,
   row_number() over (order by fiscal year,fiscal week) as chrono,
   case when chrono > count(*) over () - 52
        then 'Last52Weeks' 
        else 'NotLast52Weeks'
   end
from table
group by 1,2
```

This will result in a single STAT-step in Explain.

Answer (score 1):

I added a reverse_chrono column that effective does the opposite of your chrono column.  This results in simplified logic for your "last 52 weeks" indicate. Added a case statement to do the logic for the last 52 weeks as seen below.

```
   select fiscalyear, fiscalyearweek, chrono, reverse_chrono, case when reverse_chrono <= 52 then 'YES' else 'NO' end last_52_weeks
from "your date table/query"
```

Here is the function I used to for chrono and reverser_chrono.  In Teradata you can alias a column and use in your case statement as well.

```
    select fiscalyear, fiscal_week_of_year as fiscalweek, 
row_number() over (order by fiscalyear, fiscalweek) as chrono,
row_number() over (order by fiscalyearDESC, fiscalweekDESC) as reverse_chrono,
case when reverse_chrono <= 52 then 'YES' else 'NO' end last_52_weeks ...
```

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how to include the 'chrono' column in the original SQL statement.  My thought was to use a nested SELECT statement with rank() over the new distinct fiscalyear fiscalweek permutations, but I don't think TD will allow for ordered analytical functions within subqueries.

Comment: Updated my answer with the functions I used inside an inline view to provide the values for these.  The inline view isn't necessary in Teradata as you can use an aliased column inside of your case statement.